# Anglesharp Parse after clicking <a> which calls JavaScript function and loads additional data to page

Tags: c#, html-parsing, anglesharp

I'm trying to parse html page that have link which loads additional data to current page.
    `<a href="#" data-href="/some-url/">`
There a javascript function that calls after clicking on `<a href="#">`.

I'm able to parse data that already loaded with page, but can't parse additional block that loads by click on `<a>`. How can I parse all of the data including post-load data using AngleSharp?

JS code:

```
$('.button_add a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this);
        var page = link.data('page');
        $.ajax({
            method: 'get',
            url: link.data('href'),
            data: {page: page},
            success: function(data) {
                var linkParent = link.parent();
                var parentBlock = linkParent.parent();
                parentBlock.children('.items').first().append(data.view);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please show some code to indicate what you are doing. What is your configuration? Are you using AngleSharp.Js? How complicated is the (JS) code on the site you want to parse?

Comment: My configuration is default, I'm not figured out yet how to use AngleSharp.Js. JavaScript code is

Comment: Added JS  code to question. I found that it loads json file with html code, I assume other way to parse is add that html to originalk document and parse.  But is it possible to run JavaScript with AngleSharp itself?

Comment: As noted that is `AngleSharp.Js`, however, its only experimental. If the script is only based on jQuery it may work, but I have no idea. Prerequisite is that you load everything as it should be done (e.g., like a webbrowser). For this the configuration needs to configure the loader correctly. Please post your configuration ...

Comment: my initial configuration was Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader(); later I added Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithJs()

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to allow AngleSharp to load JS files.

```
var config = Configuration.Default
    .WithDefaultLoader(new LoaderOptions { IsResourceLoadingEnabled = true })
    .WithJs();
```

Keep in mind that AngleSharp.Js may not be able to deal with the complexity of the given script. Check the debug output for any exceptions.